# have value of variable take on whether two other variables equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm having a hard time expressing something in a linear program I am writing.  I have two variables `a` and `b`.  I want the variable `c` to be strictly binary and take on the value of 0 when `a` and `b` are equal, and 1 otherwise.  Does anyone know of a good way to express this linearly?

Let me clarify... this has to be expressed linearly, i.e., you can't use an if() statement or some sort of short handed (a==b), because `==` isn't a linear operation? (is that terminology correct?)

Comment: What language?.

Comment: I personally am using ZIMPL and SCIP.  But if it can be expressed generically, I am sure I can translate it to the proper language.

Comment: $int a;
int b;
int c;

c = a + b;

if (a = b)
\hspace{10 pt} c = 0
else
\hspace{10 pt}c = 1$

Comment: I can't use if() statements on variables, and where is `c` in your equation?

Comment: $\large{\tt C}\quad$ and $\quad\large{\tt C++}\quad$ languages:
$\large{\tt c = 1 - ( a==b );}$ .

Answer (score 0):

What can you use, then? How about dividing by abs(b-a)? If an error is returned, they are equal. Do you have a bit wise XOR?